# Email management for adding new email and setting an email as primary email

Tags: meteor, user-accounts, account-management

Meteor has tons of account management packages which all do likely the same thing as accounts-ui. For an application im working on I need a user to be able to add a new e-mailadress and set it as primary after the email is verified. For met this sounds like a really basic functionalitity but I can't find any package or code snippets which which has this implemented.

My last try is to ask you guys if you know a package or some code snippets which can give me this functionality... otherwise I need to spend a few hours working on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, this is not available in any package which adds onto the account system. However, the Meteor.users collection certainly has the ability to handle multiple emails and validations in an array (http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_users). It seems like it would just be a matter of adding the a "primary" field to the emails array. Granted, you would have to add a few UI elements to handle this functionality but over all I would imagine it should be fairly straight forward.

Comment: Not really the answer I hoped for but yeah reality is sometimes unfair. User creates an account, user verifies email associated with the account.  Next i have to implemented the following thing: user  adds new email adres, verifies the new email adres, the system automatically sets the verified automatically as the primary email and unsets the first. And maybe as an extra functionality the user must be able to change which email is his primary one.. Though its not a big functionality I cant imagine there is no package which can do that. But yeh.. a new reason to submit something to atmosphere